# ActiveRecord has_one relationship alongside a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm struggling to model a particular relationship with ActiveRecord. I currently have the following setup and working

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord:Base
    belongs_to :schedule
end
```

with a database structure that looks like this:

```
schedules
  - integer:id

tasks
  - integer:id
  - integer:schedule_id
```

What I'd like to be able to do is set one of the tasks to be the active task for a schedule by adding an "active_task_id" column to the Schedules table:

```
schedules
  - integer:id
  - integer:active_task_id

tasks
  - integer:id
  - integer:schedule_id
```

What I'm struggling with is how I should describe this within my ActiveRecord classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should look like this

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :tasks 
    belongs_to :active_task, 
               :class_name => 'Task', 
               :foreign_key => 'active_task_id'
end 

class Task < ActiveRecord:Base 
    belongs_to :schedule 
    has_one :relevant_schedule,
            :class_name => 'Schedule',
            :foreign_key => 'active_task_id'
end
```

the conceptually tricky part is defining the 'relevant_schedule' relation. this isn't really needed in most cases (i.e. will not be used by code you write), is needed for compelteness of the ORM.

it's unlikely you'll ever want to use `task.relevant_schedule` (in many cases it would be nil), you'll probably mostly want to use `schedule.active_task` in your code.

'relevant_schedule' is just an arbitrary name, you may choose any other name you like.
:class_name and :foreign_key must exactly match database and model names. perhaps the 'relevant_schedule' definition may be omitted altogether. i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'd be better off using an attribute rather than creating a separate id. Maybe your task could have a boolean column called `active`, then the active task for a schedule could be found with:

```
@schedule.tasks.select {|t|t.active?}
```

Or your could create named scope to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: This was my plan-b. Looks like I should read up on named scopes too. Thanks.